# Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded on npm start for angular

Tags: angular, npm, angular12

Getting the error 'Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded' up on running ng serve

node version:v14.17.5
npm version:6.14.14

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^12.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.9",
    "@ngui/datetime-picker": "^0.16.2",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "angular-ng-autocomplete": "^2.0.4",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.1.3",
    "exceljs": "^4.2.1",
    "faker": "^5.5.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.14",
    "material-tooltip": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-mask": "^11.1.5",
    "ngx-smart-popover": "^1.4.0",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "symbol-observable": "^1.2.0",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^6.0.0",
    "karma": "^5.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^4.0.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
```

Error in terminal (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GcHx.png)]

Tried deleting node modules ,package lock, cache clearing and reinstalling npm

Comment: The problem seems to be with your application. Circular dependencies/imports can be a problem. This doesn't seem to be a problem with npm itself and your dependencies. You would have to share the application code, maybe then you would get more help.

Comment: see if in **your modules** you have a circular dependency, e.g. you have a data.module that import shared.module and shared.module import data.module

Comment: It may also be helpful to try hiding some code and removing pieces until your app can load. Then incrementally add back parts to see when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try running following in cli

```
node --max_old_space_size=4048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve
```

or

```
node --max_old_space_size=8096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve
```

If it works modify your package.json as follows

[image]

Comment: Still i am seeing same error coming up